# Generating a Stata date variable from ISO datetime string

Tags: stata

I have datetime strings that look like this:

```
starttime = 2017-01-03T00:00:00.000000-05:00
```

I would like to generate Stata datetime variables from that sting, but am having difficulty. This is the code I am using:

```
generate stataDate = clock(starttime, "YMD!THH:MM:SS")
```

Do you know the correct mast to use with this string? I have been looking through the documentation but cannot find an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following may point you in a useful direction.

```
clear
input str32 starttime
"2017-01-03T00:00:00.000000-05:00"
"2017-01-03T12:34:56.654321-05:00"
end
generate double sd = clock(starttime,"YMD#hms##")
format sd %tcCCYY-NN-DD_HH:MM:SS.sss
```

which yields

```
. list, clean

                              starttime                        sd  
  1.   2017-01-03T00:00:00.000000-05:00   2017-01-03 00:00:00.000  
  2.   2017-01-03T12:34:56.654321-05:00   2017-01-03 12:34:56.654
```

Worth noting is that the limit on precision for Stata datetime values is milliseconds: those are the units in which the values are stored. Also crucial is that datetime values must be stored as a double numeric value rather than a float, which cannot retain full accuracy.

Stata's date and time variables are complicated and there is a lot to learn. If you have not already read the very detailed Chapter 24 (Working with dates and times) of the *Stata User's Guide* PDF, do so now. If you have, it's time for a refresher. After that, the `help datetime` documentation will usually be enough to point the way. You can't remember everything; even the most experienced users end up referring to the `help datetime` documentation or back to the manual for details. But at least you will get a good understanding of the basics and the underlying principles. An investment of time that will be amply repaid.